# use Lottie Animations with flutter web HTML renderer

Tags: flutter, web, animation, lottie

is it possible to use Lottie Animation json file in flutter web while using HTML renderer?

I'm using [Lottie package](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) but not working for web.

Comment: any news on that?

Comment: As of september 2023 with flutter 3.13.4 - it's still only working with canvaskit renderer, not HTML renderer.

Answer (score 0):

As I just tripped on a problem using mobile browsers (see [Flutter Web: Lottie Animation is cropped on Android Chrome, but Windows Chrome is okay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687624/flutter-web-lottie-animation-is-cropped-on-android-chrome-but-windows-chrome-i) )
my personal answer is yes+no:

As of Sep 2022: I you are building for desktop browsers only, Flutter's HTML renderer seems to be fine.
If also mobile browsers, such as Chrome, shall be usable, HTML Renderer does not work cleanly for any lottie animation. Use canvaskit renderer in that case.